# How to model async service task in camunda and implement it in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

I use Camunda as bpmn engine in my spring boot application

**Main idea:**
The first process is started in the controller, and after the response is returned to the client, the Second process should start. 
I do this using @Async(spring framework) to start the second process and I have two bpmn diagrams:
[firstProcess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLFUi.png)
[secondProcess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r08Ig.png)

Simple implementation of the idea:

```
@RestController
public class SimpleController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomService asyncService;
    @Autowired
    private CustomService syncService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/request")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendQuestion() {
        //start process described in first.bpmn
        syncService.startProcess("firstProcess");
        //start process described in second.bpmn asynchronously
        //controller responses to client without waiting for ending secondProcess
        asyncService.startProcess("secondProcess");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class AsyncService implements CustomService {

    @Autowired
    private RuntimeService runtimeService;

    @Async
    public void startProcess(String key) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //
        }
        runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(key);
    }
}
```

**Questions:**
Is there a way to do these two processes in one process (as shown at both processes)?
How should I implement this in the spring boot app?
[bothProcess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX6g8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `Call Activity Task` specifying `BPMN` as `CallActivity Type` and corresponding process ids in `Called Element` field on the properties panel.
Also don't forget uncheck `Startable` checkbox for your subprocesses.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me. Do you know the way to have this is in one BPMN diagram? Because now I need to have three BPMN diagram(for firstProcess, secondProcess, and for the process with Call Activity Task)

Comment: Consider the use of `Embedded SubProcess`.
Might be useful [https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/bpmn20/subprocesses/](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/bpmn20/subprocesses/)